# Constant length of line segment through $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves

"Let $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ be regular curves on the plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$) such that, for all $t$, the line through $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ is orthogonal to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $t$. Prove that the line segment between $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ has constant length (i.e., it's length is independent of $t$). " 
Well, this seems pretty simple, but I am struggling a bit to equate the line, since the parameter $t$ appears a lot: let $r(t)$ be the line determined by the points $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$, in such a way that $r(t) = \alpha(t) + (\beta(t) - \alpha(t)) \, t$, for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Now, looking at $\ell(t) = \left\| \beta(t) - \alpha(t)\right\|^2 = \left\langle \beta(t) - \alpha(t), \, \beta(t) - \alpha(t)\right\rangle $ and differentiating, one has 
$\ell'(t) = 2 \left\langle \beta'(t) - \alpha'(t), \, \beta(t) - \alpha(t)\right\rangle$; how can we conclude that this inner product is zero?

Comment: Your $r(t)$ defines a curve (just like $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$). Do define a set of lines you need two parameters:
$$
r(t,s) = \alpha(t) + (\beta(t) - \alpha(t)) s, \quad s \in [0, 1]
$$
Here $t$ determines the intersection points between the line and $\alpha, \beta$ and $s$ is the parameter of the segment ($s = 0$ is the point on $\alpha$ and $s = 1$ is the point on $\beta$). And I don't see where you've used the orthogonality condition

Comment: Think about the interpretation of the term $\langle\beta',\beta-\alpha\rangle$ and the term $\langle\alpha',\beta-\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: As you said, the parameter $t$ “appears a lot.” So don’t reuse that letter; see if you can find another letter.